# How to handle CSRF token using XMLHTTPRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, csrf

I am using an API which is protected by CSRF. So I need to do a get call to fetch CSRF token and then pass the same token to do POST call.

Below is the way I tried, but i always get CSRF Token Validation failed as response for the POST call.

```
var tryout = new XMLHttpRequest();
tryout.open("GET", "/api/1.0/csrf");
tryout.withCredentials = true;
tryout.setRequestHeader("x-csrf-token", "fetch");    
tryout.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
tryout.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
tryout.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log(this);
    var csrfToken = this.getResponseHeader('x-csrf-token');
    if(tryout.readyState == 4){
        console.log(csrfToken);
        tryout.open('POST', '/api/1.0/create');
        tryout.setRequestHeader('x-csrf-token', this.getResponseHeader('x-csrf-token'));            
        tryout.onreadystatechange = function () {
            console.log("call 2");
            console.log(this.responseText);
        };
        tryout.send();
    }
};
tryout.send();
```

I am suspecting may be POST call is starting new session and so CSRF is not valid for that session.

Please guide me How to do two xhr calls in same session ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried sync calls with XMLHTTPRequest using same xhr object for both calls ( fetching csrf token and next http post call passing csrf token in header and it worked. Below is the sample code.

```
var res = null;
var tryout = new XMLHttpRequest();  
tryout.open("GET", "/odata/1.0/service.svc", false);
tryout.withCredentials = true;
tryout.setRequestHeader("x-csrf-token", "fetch");    
tryout.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
tryout.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
tryout.send(null);

if(tryout.readyState === 4){
  var csrfToken = tryout.getResponseHeader('x-csrf-token');   

  tryout.open('POST', '/odata/1.0/service.svc/Clients', false);
  tryout.setRequestHeader('x-csrf-token', csrfToken);       
  tryout.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
  tryout.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

  tryout.send(JSON.stringify(obj));

  if(tryout.readyState === 4){
      res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is obj? Is it defined anywhere?

Comment: Yes McJohnson, obj is defined, its request body. somehow i have missed to copy that part of snippet here.

Answer (score 0):

"x-csrf-token", "fetch" is for the GET method to fetch the data. Then you will get the csrf token value. Just copy that and add that in your code may be it will work.